# MultiPOCO queries firing error message

Tags: t-sql, petapoco

I have a query as

```
return Connection.db.Fetch<Issue, Condition , Result , Status>(
    "SELECT * FROM Issue I, Condition C, Result R, Status S " +
    "LEFT JOIN Issue ON Condition .ID = Issue.ConditionID" +
    "LEFT JOIN Issue ON Result.ID = Issue.ResultID" +              
    "LEFT JOIN Issue ON Status.ID = Issue.StatusID " +
    "WHERE Issue.ID= "+ issueId);
```

which is giving the error message:

> The multi-part identifier "Condition.ID" could not be bound.
>   The objects "Issue" and "Issue" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them.

What is worng with the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're joining to **Issue** table several times, but never use aliases. This is especially a problem because you've added the same table to `FROM` part of your `SELECT` clause. Always use aliases in joins. It's the safest way.

So whenever you said Issue.ID query engine could not resolve to which one you're referring. Is it to the one in `FROM` part or the one in `JOIN` part.

Try out this code:

```
return Connection.db.Fetch<Issue, Condition , Result , Status>(
    "SELECT * FROM Issue I, Condition C, Result R, Status S " +
    "LEFT JOIN Issue i1 ON C.ID = i1.ConditionID" +
    "LEFT JOIN Issue i2 ON R.ID = i2.ResultID" +              
    "LEFT JOIN Issue i3 ON S.ID = i3.StatusID " +
    "WHERE I.ID = " + issueId);
```

And apart from that I strongly suggest you use parameters instead of string concatenation:

```
return Connection.db.Fetch<Issue, Condition , Result , Status>(
    "SELECT * FROM Issue I, Condition C, Result R, Status S " +
    "LEFT JOIN Issue i1 ON C.ID = i1.ConditionID" +
    "LEFT JOIN Issue i2 ON R.ID = i2.ResultID" +              
    "LEFT JOIN Issue i3 ON S.ID = i3.StatusID " +
    "WHERE I.ID = @0", issueId); // see the change in this line
```

### After some thought this is actually invalid SQL query

The problem that you're having is **not PetaPoco related** at all. You've actually written an invalid SQL query. If you'd run this same statement in SSMS you'd get the same error and that's because your query is interpreted as:

```
SELECT * FROM Issue I, Condition C, Result R,

    (Status S 

        LEFT JOIN Issue i1
        ON C.ID = i1.ConditionID

        LEFT JOIN Issue i2
        ON R.ID = i2.ResultID

        LEFT JOIN Issue i3
        ON S.ID = i3.StatusID 
    )

WHERE I.ID = x;
```

And that's the main reason why the first two joins fail. The last one is the only one that works, because it sees both tables. You probably thought that your select makes a result of those tables and then joins as in:

```
SELECT * FROM (Issue I, Condition C, Result R, Status S)
    LEFT JOIN ...
```

But that is not the case.

Depending on what kind of results you want (you may end up with a large result set the way that you're doing it) you will have to rewrite your query to a different form and possibly omit the multi table list in your `FROM` part.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I am still having the error The multi-part identifier "C.ID" could not be bound.
The multi-part identifier "P.ID" could not be bound.

Comment: I don't see no **P** alias. Are you sure the problem that you're having is within this query?

Comment: I`m sorry I changed the message accidentally ...The multi-part identifier "C.ID" could not be bound. The multi-part identifier "R.ID" could not be bound.

Comment: @learning: I edited my answer to explain the problem, but I can't give your the solution because I don't know what kind of results you actually want. The main thing is that this problem you're having is not related to PetaPoco but is the fact that your **query is invalid**.

Comment: Indeed the issue was with the query. Thanks @Robert